# Prisma Error: Argument 'where' of type UserWhereUniqueInput needs at least one of 'id' or 'email' arguments

Tags: node.js, mongodb, prisma, express-jwt

I'm encountering an issue with Prisma while trying to update a user's password in my Node.js application. Whenever I attempt to change the password using the `changePassword` function in my `authController.js` file, I receive the following error:

```
PrismaClientValidationError: Invalid `prisma.user.findUnique()` invocation:
Argument `where` of type UserWhereUniqueInput needs at least one of `id` or `email` arguments.
```

Here's the relevant code snippet from my `authController.js` file:

```js
const changePassword = async (req, res) => {
  // #swagger.tags = ['Authentication']
  /* #swagger.security = [{
        "bearerAuth": []
    }] */
  const { userId } = req.user; // Extracted from JWT token in auth middleware
  const { oldPassword, newPassword } = req.body;

  try {
    // Fetch user from database using userId
    const user = await prisma.user.findUnique({ where: { id: userId } });
    if (!user) {
      return res.status(404).json({ message: "User not found" });
    }

    // Validate old password
    const isMatch = await bcrypt.compare(oldPassword, user.password);
    if (!isMatch) {
      return res.status(400).json({ message: "Incorrect old password" });
    }

    // Hash new password
    const salt = await bcrypt.genSalt(10);
    const hashedPassword = await bcrypt.hash(newPassword, salt);

    // Update user's password
    await prisma.user.update({
      where: { id: userId },
      data: { password: hashedPassword },
    });

    res.json({ message: "Password updated successfully" });
  } catch (error) {
    console.error("Error changing password:", error);
    res.status(500).json({ message: "Server error" });
  }
};
```

and this is `verifyToken` middleware:

```js
const jwt = require('jsonwebtoken');

const verifyToken = (req, res, next) => {
  const authHeader = req.header('Authorization');
  if (!authHeader) return res.status(401).json({ error: true, message: 'Authorization header missing' });

  const token = authHeader.split(" ")[1];
  if (!token) return res.status(401).json({ error: true, message: 'Token not provided' });

  jwt.verify(token, process.env.JWT_SECRET, (err, user) => {
    if (err) {
      console.error('JWT verification error:', err);
      return res.status(403).json({ error: true, message: 'Invalid token' });
    }
    req.user = user;
    next();
  });
};


module.exports = verifyToken
```

I'm not sure why I'm getting this error since I'm providing the `id` argument in the `where` clause when calling `prisma.user.findUnique`. Any help on resolving this issue would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

this is the error:

```
    try {
      // Fetch user from database
→.    const user = await prisma.user.findUnique({
         where: {
           id: undefined,
       ?   email?: String,
       ?   AND?: UserWhereInput | UserWhereInput[],
       ?   OR?: UserWhereInput[],
       ?   NOT?: UserWhereInput | UserWhereInput[],
       ?   username?: StringFilter | String,
       ?   password?: StringFilter | String,
       ?   createdAt?: DateTimeFilter | DateTime,
       ?   updatedAt?: DateTimeFilter | DateTime,
       ?   role?: EnumRoleFilter | Role,
       ?   profile?: ProfileNullableRelationFilter | ProfileWhereInput | Null,
       ?   review?: ReviewListRelationFilter
         },
         select: {
           email: true,
           username: true,
           password: true,
           createdAt: true,
           updatedAt: true,
           role: true,
           profile: true
         }
       })

Argument `where` of type UserWhereUniqueInput needs at least one of `id` or `email` arguments. Available options are marked with ?.
```

Answer (score 1):

The error Prisma is giving you is:

```
Argument `where` of type UserWhereUniqueInput needs at least one of `id` or `email` arguments.
```

This means that Prisma is not receiving either the `id` or `email` argument in the `prisma.user.findUnique` call. This probably means that `req.user.userId` is not present within your `changePassword` function. I would start debugging there to guarantee that `req.user.userId` exists before passing it to Prisma, because Prisma won't work as intended until you do.

Comment: Almost. It's not the update that is failing but `user.findUnique`. It's right there in the error message which OP posted: `const user = await prisma.user.findUnique({ where: { id: undefined }) // ..`

Comment: Good point - they are both failing, but for the same reason (that `userId` is `undefined`)